# Run PHP script at regular intervals using CRON

Tags: php, cron

I am kinda newbie to this, I have a php script which I want to execute after every 1 hour, for this I updated the crontab file inside the /etc directory but I am not able to see whether its actually being called.

Here's the entry in my crontab file

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -o temp.txt http://myurl.com/postparser.php
```

I am not even able to see any temp.txt file getting generated
Can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

try running

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/file/postparser.php
```

Change the `/usr/bin/php` part to your php executable path.

Comment: and in php file all paths need to be absolute

Comment: in my server I dont see any such directory I have only usr/bin but no php . what should I do ?

Comment: write a page with only the following function `phpinfo();`. it will give you your php configuration details. In that find `PHPRC` which will be a dir. that dir will have `php` in it. So if your `PHPRC` has value `/usr/lib/php` try changing `/usr/bin/php' to `/usr/lib/php/php`

Comment: I do not see anything called PHPRC I think the server is using Zend framework..in that case what should be the path

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this but, changing just the file would have no effect.
Try editing the tasks using the command `crontab -e` ("e" for editing).

If you want to edit the crontab for a certain user, use the `-u` parameter

for more, check the man:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab

Good luck